# script has a huge delay at the beginning

Tags: python

I have multiple python scripts in various complexity I am running from another application as part of data load steps.

Some are in production for more than 2 years some new.

I have observed lately a script starts and does nothing for 10+ minutes.

Example : The application has the start timestamp as 2022-05-17 15:48:42

The first entry in the log file for this script is 2022-05-17 16:01:04

Script logs the start time as a first step.

The list of libraries imported for the example run above is a short one since this is one of the areas I looked at

```
import snowflake.connector
import json
import os
import datetime
import threading
from pathlib import Path
```

Any ideas what could be causing this behavior?
How can I further debug this?

Update : Here is the minimal example of the script

```
import snowflake.connector
import json
import os
import datetime
import threading
from pathlib import Path

def to_log(msg, include_timestamp=True):
    """Write the log entry to log file"""

    # add the current date to the log file name in order to create a file for everyday
    log_file = Path(
        work_dir
        / (
            f"log/kafka_loader_"
            + "{:%Y%m%d}".format(datetime.datetime.now())
            + ".log"
        )
    )

    if include_timestamp:
        msg = "{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}".format(datetime.datetime.now()) + f" {msg}"
    print(msg)

    with open(log_file, "a") as l_f:
        l_f.write(msg + "\n")

def proces():
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":

    to_log("Starting a new session")

    process()

    to_log("Session completed")
```

The application used to invoke the script is called WhereScape.
In the UI I see the started start timestamp above.

Comment: Can you post a [mre] of a script that shows the same behavior? Imports can take some time, but usually not *that much*, there must be something else in your script or related to your machine that is causing this. One option would be launching it under `strace -f` and looking at what happens.

Comment: You say "The application has the start timestamp of.." What is "the application" in this context and how do you derive that start time? Also for the "First entry in the log file" when is that captured in your script? In order to help we would need to understand what is happening between those two timestamps and how those timestamps are captured.

Comment: How are the timestamps being generated? If you're running a script which is redirecting the output to a file, Python can buffer that output until it gets enough to write to disk. If you then use a program like `ts` to add timestamps to the output, then the timestamps will be the time the buffer was flushed, not the time the print() actually ran. You can try setting the env var `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` to check this possibility.

Comment: I have updated the question with Application name and minimal reproducible example

Comment: Have you considered profiling your code? Even with the [builtin profilers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html), you could probably understand what is taking so much time.

Comment: @BlackBeans when I run the code from command line manually it runs fine. The issue happens when it's invoked from the app.

Comment: @demircioglu profiling can be done in production. Depending on the profiler you use, you might have a more important overhead, but it's overall quite reasonable (especially if your script is wasting ~15minutes, I wouldn't say performance is critical...)